# Opening permanent window from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension (the Chrome version of [Selenium Builder](http://www.sebuilder.com/)) which needs to create a permanently open window for the extension's UI. I've tried using the following code in a browser action popup:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  chrome.windows.create({url: "gui.html", width: 500, height: 600});
  close();
});
```

This works, except that the created window appears *behind* the existing windows. This may be related to [this Chrome bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113572).

Is there a sane way of opening a permanent window and making it appear in front? `focus()` and `chrome.windows.update(w.id, { focused: true })` don't do anything, and using `window.open` of course opens the window in a tab.

Comment: Have you tried creating it in your background scripts and focusing it there? (You'd post a message to your background script from within your `document.addEventListener` callback that would tell your background script to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a Chrome packaged app, which will allow any number of windows to be opened with a lifetime separate from browser tabs, and then have it talk to your extension with chrome.runtime.sendMessage. [Here is a good sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/messaging) of the concept.